# Are old order stormtrooper helmets more sight restrictive than clone helmets?

Tags: star-wars, armor

In the last episode of Star Wars Rebels, Rex had to disguise himself as a stormtrooper. When their cover was blown, Kanaan and Rex had to fight out if a star destroyer. During the firefight, Rex missed a few shots and Kanaan comments on how he "shoots like a storm trooper." Rex threw a tantrum, removing his helmet and heaving it at the attacking stormtroopers and blasting two or three of them, saying something along the lines of

> "it's these dang helmets."

If you look at the images, you will see an evolution. Clones had larger HUDS and could see more of the surrounding environment. Stormtroopers look like they will have crappy peripheral vision. New order troopers seem to have improved helmets to change this.

My question: other than this scene, is there any in universe proof that stormtrooper armor, helmets in particular, are less effective at displaying visual information to the trooper?

[image: clone helmets]

[image: trooper helmets over time]

Comment: @Hatandboots Not exactly the answer I was looking for though...

Comment: Are Old Order Stormtroopers ones that [ride in horse buggies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Order_Mennonite)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the visual dictionary for episode four through six (not sure on the canon level of this), but the stormtrooper helmets were equipped with eye equipment that allowed for a holographic view of their surroundings.  As you can see in the image provided, there are little projectors that would line up with the wearers eye.  So while on the outside it looks like they wouldn't be able to see that well, they were in fact able to.  [image: here]

Comment: I guess there is no excuse for their shooting then...

Comment: As an addendum to this answer, the pre-Disney EU established that the aforementioned holographic system only activated when the authorized wearer of the helmet put it on, hence Luke's complaint that "I can't see a thing in this helmet". While the holo-system, and apparently all the rest of the components in the Visual Dictionary photo, are canon due to publications reusing the pictures and labels, the onboard security system isn't recanonized yet AFAIK.

Answer (score 7):

To add some *video-game level canon* to the other answer, in the game [Star Wars: Republic Commando](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Republic_Commando) we see through the eyes of a stormtrooper in the year 22 BBY.

[image]

This is the only instance that I could find where we see what a clone sees *through* a helmet. I do realize this is a video game and that this probably is not an accurate representation.

<sub>This is a fantastic game by the way, it's Metroid prime meets Star Wars!</sub>

Comment: Man, what a great game that was!